# How can add Bearer before token

Tags: java

[PostMan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltmRW.png)

My `BaseController` code

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Autowired
private UserService userService;

public User handleTokenAccess(String encodeString) throws Exception {

    byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(encodeString);
    String decodedMime = new String(decodedBytes);

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        UserClient map = mapper.readValue(decodedMime, UserClient.class);

        User user = userService.findOne(map.getUserId());
        if (user != null)
            return user;
        else
            throw new Exception();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Sai token , vui lòng chim cút");
    }
}
```

My `CategoriesController` code

```java
@RestController

@RequestMapping("/api/categories")
public class CategoriesController extends BaseController {

    @Autowired
    private CategoriesService categoriesService;

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/create-category", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<BaseResponse> create(@Valid @RequestBody CRUDCategories wrapper,
            @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization") String token) throws Exception {
        BaseResponse response = new BaseResponse();
        User userToken = this.handleTokenAccess(token);
        Categories category = categoriesService.spUCreateCategory(userToken.getId(), wrapper.get_name(),
                wrapper.getDescpiption(), wrapper.get_sort());
        response.setData(new CategoriesResponse(category));
        return new ResponseEntity<BaseResponse>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Add it manually in your token in Postman request header.
2. There is a tab 'Authorization' in Postman, then select bearer and add your token.
BTW, you should implement spring security rather than handle it manually.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.